# Cannot create an instance of viewmodel while using Jetpack Compose navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using navigation component for jetpack compose in my app like this:

```
@Composable
fun FoodiumNavigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.Main.route,
    ) {
        composable(Screen.Main.route) {
            MainScreen(navController)
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

And I am getting `viewmodel` in my `MainScreen` composable like this:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val mainViewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()
    ...
}
```

which is giving me a runtime exception as `Cannot create an instance of class com.package.main.MainViewModel`.

Here, I am stating that this only happens while using navigation component, i.e. everything was working fine and `mainViewModel` was successfully instantiated before using navigation component in my app.

The `MainViewModel` is like this:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(private val postRepository: PostRepository) :
    ViewModel() {

    private val _postsLiveDataState = MutableLiveData<UiState<List<Post>>>()
    val postLiveState: LiveData<UiState<List<Post>>> = _postsLiveDataState

    init {
        getPostsState()
    }

    private fun getPostsState() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            postRepository.getAllPosts()
                .onStart { _postsLiveDataState.value = UiState(loading = true) }
                .map { resource -> UiState.fromResource(resource) }
                .collect { state -> _postsLiveDataState.value = state }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the [existing Hilt issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2166#issuecomment-723775543)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your @HiltViewModel is scoped to the navigation graph use hiltNavGraphViewModel() instead of viewModel() to initialize. For more reference [android documentaion](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation)

**Update**

hiltNavGraphViewModel() is now deprecated, use hiltViewModel() instead

Thanks to [Narek Hayrapetyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4477481/narek-hayrapetyan) for the reminder

Comment: I noticed that `hiltNavGraphViewModel` will return the same view model after navigating to a different view and then back. Would it also be possible to get a new model instance after each navigation?

Comment: hiltNavGraphViewModel is deprecated, should be used `hiltViewModel ()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

`hiltNavGraphViewModel` is deprecated, should be used `hiltViewModel()` instead

also add dependency `androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03`

Answer (score 3):

You should add this

> ```
> implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")
> ```

then you can use this code for create instance of your viewmodel

> ```
> val viewModel: YourViewModelClass= hiltViewModel()
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `viewModel()` as well, but check that owning `Activity` or `Fragment` has been annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint`.